# refactoring variables access automatically

Tags: c++, eclipse, oop, encapsulation, automated-refactoring

I have changed access to a class variables from being public to private,

then created getters & setters (100 variables)

sometime later, after that is completed,

how can I automate, accessing any of these variables directly to set/get without going through every single one of these 100 variable. sometime a variable is accessed almost everywhere throughout a big project, so it is a bit tough to do by hand.

I am using Eclipse IDE, c++ project

Comment: I don't think you can easily just change the protection of things and "Find and Replace" on them. There's not an easy way to do this to an existing part of a project.

Comment: Just a thought: if you have 100 data members, maybe you should refactor the container class and break it into smaller classes.

Comment: Hence the reason you don't let your data members be accessed publicly ... changing a public interface is a PITA.

Comment: Pulling out the gut of you classes with functions instead of direct variable access doesn't make your code OOP at all.. except if you really do something beside simple assignment/return.

Comment: @EitanT I hope the OP didn't mean 100 members in one class but members in lots of classes (~100).

Comment: @g-makulik 100 classes sounds just as wrong...

Comment: You might use an appropriate UML tool in the 1st place, you could reverse engineer the code base, script model changes and regenerate the source code. This could help at least to automatically generate the necessary getter/setter functions.

Comment: ... extending my last comment: Especially if you have already done this once now. What you seem to have now sounds not like being a really thoughtful system architecture design!

Comment: @aboody Seriously! Use what you have as a prototype to retrieve the requirements and redesign from scratch. Manipulating in parts and guts of spaghetti code never did turn into any better results as for my experience.

Answer (score 3):

If your project is really large & you're retrofitting private member control into it, you may find it helpful to go an alternate route:  Don't implement getters at all....  just implement the setters.  Define a `const` public reference to each underlying private member variable, which serves as the "getter" for it.  Any code that reads this data can remain unchanged; you only have to update the code that *sets* these variables, which may be a lot less painful to update.  If you go this route, you'll have to initialize these public references in the constructors, like this:

```
class fred {
public:
    fred() : stone(_stone) {} // every constructor must initialize all public references like this
    void set_stone(int s) { _stone = s; }
    int get_stone() { return _stone; } // Instead of this (or, in ADDITION to this), do this....
    const int& stone; // const public reference to internal private data member
private:
    int _stone;
}
```

You can go with that solution permanently, or only until you ("someday") finish updating all of your getters.  Personally for classes where the data types of their internal data is pretty obvious & won't change, I prefer this solution anyway, as code written with it is just easier to read.  I *wish* that C++ had an `operator classmember_setter<membername>()` feature that would allow you to write a setter method that would look just like you were simply accessing a data member instead of calling a method on it; that would result in a whole lot neater code than you get with setter methods.

Comment: I like this Idea, however I wish for an IDE automation, similar to generating getters and setters.